# PHP echoed javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Consider the following:**

```
<div id="BAN">
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var nextTimes = 0;    
      window.onload = function() {
         acquireComments();
         nextTimes= nextTimes+10;
      };    
      function acquireComments(){
         var artID = "<?php echo $GOTID; ?>";
         var currentvalue = document.getElementById('BAN').innerHTML;
         //console.log(currentvalue);
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'recieveComments.php?article=2&time='+nextTimes+'',
            success: function(data){
               document.getElementById('BAN').innerHTML = data;
            }
         });
      }    
   </script>
</div>
```

**And in the receivecomments.php file:**

```
echo "<div id=\"CommentDiv\" style=\"margin-top:10px;webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none; -moz-text-size-adjust:none;text-size-adjust:none;\">
    <a id=\"alink\" style=\"font-size:16px;webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none; -moz-text-size-adjust:none;text-size-adjust:none;\"href=\"$url\">$name</a>
    <p style=\"webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none; -moz-text-size-adjust:none;text-size-adjust:none;\">$comment</p>
    <div id=\"ReplyComment\">
       <a id=\"Reply\">Reply</a>
       <script type=\"text/javascript\">
           setInterval(function test(){
               console.log(\"Hello World\");
           },10);               
       </script>
    </div>
</div>";
```

The above code in the recievecomments.php file is echoed and is displayed on screen. However the console does not log "Hello World". I printed the innerhtml of the "BAN" div and it appears that the java script code is in their but it is not getting executed. I tried putting in an alert instead and I tried making it change the CSS but still does not work. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong. I am using PHP 5.5

Comment: This is working for me:

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>function test(){console.log('Hello World');}setInterval(test,10);</script>";

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript inserted as DOM text will not execute.
You can use eval() but DONT.